# How to tell Hibernate to use a proxy?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Currently using **Hibernate** for object persistence, with **Snowflake** as my database. Hibernate hangs when it tries to connect & commit to the database. This is because my company requires us to connect via a *proxy*.

I read the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html). The documentation does not define how Hibernate is to connect via a proxy... is this supported? How does Hibernate connect to objects on a proxy, or is it even possible?

My Hibernate config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="MySessionFactory">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:snowflake://made.up.location.snowflakecomputing.com</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myUsername</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mySchema</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm hoping we can define properties in a similar manner to this:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("user", "myUser");
        properties.put("password", "myPassword");
        properties.put("warehouse", "warehouseName");
        properties.put("db", "databaseName");
        properties.put("schema", "mySchema");
        properties.put("role", "myRole");
        properties.put("proxyHost", "proxy.myServer.com");
        properties.put("proxyPort", "80");
        properties.put("useProxy", "true");
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#connecting-using-a-proxy-server was this already referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this issue by placing all parameters into the connection string in the following manner:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:snowflake://myCompany.us-west-3.snowflakecomputing.com/?user=username&amp;password=password&amp;warehouse=WH_Name&amp;db=DB_Name&amp;schema=SCHEMA&amp;role=MYROLE&amp;proxyHost=proxy.com&amp;proxyPort=50&amp;useProxy=true</property>
```

This bypassed any difficult configuration settings with Snowflake, and I am now able to connect perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link to connect Hibernate with Snowflake.
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/snowflake-jdbc-hibernate.rst

Comment: Already read that article. Does not explain how to handle proxies with configuration file.